# Increase Executors while running Junit Test case in Spark Scala Application in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I need to run Junit test case for spark scala application on IntelliJ Idea.
By Default job is run using one executor.
My Machine has 4 cores. Can i increase number of executors to 4?
if yes, Then how?

Comment: how do you create your spark session? you could specify the master url as local[4]

Comment: Thanks Sai for information

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would not do that, even if its possible using Spark Standalone or Yarn. You have 1 machine, so you should use `local`mode for unit tests.

You can use `spark.master = local[4]` or `local[*]`. In this case, you will still have 1 executor, but 4 core which can process tasks in parallel. For unit-tests, this is usually enough.